# Python math module logarithm functions

Tags: python, math, ieee-754

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inaccurate Logarithm in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931995/inaccurate-logarithm-in-python)

Why are the `math.log10(x)` and `math.log(x,10)` results different?

```
In [1]: from math import *

In [2]: log10(1000)
Out[2]: 3.0

In [3]: log(1000,10)
Out[3]: 2.9999999999999996
```

Comment: Some floating point precision problem

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931995/inaccurate-logarithm-in-python

Comment: It looks like log(1000,10) is being interpreted as log(1000)/log(10), which makes sense. Then it comes down to the difference between having a straight log10 function versus the floating point error from doing two logs and dividing them. It isn't surprising that the former is more accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`math.log10` and `math.log(x, 10)` are using different algorithm, and the former is usually more accurate. Actually, it's a known issue(Issue6765): [math.log, log10 inconsistency](http://bugs.python.org/issue6765).

One may think in this way: `log10(x)` has a fixed base, hence it can be computed directly by some mathematical approximation formula(e.g. Taylor series), while `log(x, 10)` comes from a more general formula with two variables, which may be indirectly calculated by `log(x) / log(10)`(at least the precision of log(10) will affect the precision of quotient). So it's natural that the former way is both faster and more accurate, and that is reasonable considering that it takes advantage of a pre-known logarithmic base(i.e. 10).

Answer (score 5):

It's a known bug : http://bugs.python.org/issue3724

Seems logX(y) is always more precise than the equivalent  log(Y, X).

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `log(1000, 10)` is computed internally as `log(1000) / log(10)`. This can be verified empirically:

```
In [3]: math.log(1000, 10) == math.log(1000) / math.log(10)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: math.log10(1000) == math.log(1000) / math.log(10)
Out[4]: False
```

The results of neither `log(1000)` nor `log(10)` can be represented as `float`, so the final result is also inexact.