# Looking for Fast log10floor implementation for Python

Tags: python

Is there any library that implements an efficient `log10floor` function in Python?

Python has [accuracy problems for large numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931995/inaccurate-logarithm-in-python), but if one simply rounds a logarithm to its floor, then it's possible to have a very simple implementation. I'd rather not code my own, so I'm looking for one.

As an example for Java, Guava implements [a very fast `log10` function](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/LongMath.java#L162) when you want to round to floor.

Comment: This isn't a problem for Python, this is inherent to any binary floating point representation...

Comment: Thanks for the condescending explanation. I understand that. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't depend on the floating point representation of a logarithm (see Guava link).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to work with integers, there's always this slow-but-simple method:

```
def log10floor(x):
    return len("%d" % x) - 1
```

Comment: Isn't the OP specifically looking for a _fast_ implementation?