# Math.log wrong results for big numbers

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math

`math.log2` and `math.log` are giving me wrong results for some high numbers, tested it via online py interpreter and on a local machine.

```
>>>print(2**72)  

>>>4722366482869645213696 #Correct

>>>math.log2(4722366482869645213697)

>>>72.0 #Wrong

>>>math.log(4722366482869645213697,2)

>>>72.0 #Wrong

>>>math.log2(39614081257132168796771975174)

>>>95.0 #Wrong

>>>print(2**95)

>>>39614081257132168796771975168 #Correct
```

Am I missing something or its some bug?

Comment: Why is 72.0 "wrong"?  What float would you like instead?

Comment: Hey.72.0 Suggests that its the same as 2**72 and its not, it should return something like 71.xxxxxxxxx.

Comment: Your question is about checking if an integer is a power of two. Next time you ask, include the context of your question and which problem you are trying to solve. Meanwhile, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer is about *72.0000000000000000000003*.

The absolute error being smaller than the floating point error in that range, you got the closest [floating point approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/5079316) of `log2(72)` a computer can store with a 64 bits float.

If you want to check whether an integer is an exact power of two, then you can check whether only it's left-most bit is a 1.

```
if 1 << (x.bit_length() - 1) == x:
    print("x is a power of 2")
```

Comment: And how to use decimal with math.log? It seems it returns result in a float by default.

Comment: You will find an answer to that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931995/inaccurate-logarithm-in-python). Although, do you really need such precision?

Comment: Cant find there anything that works with my examples, I need to perfectly tell if the number is the power of 2 on such high numbers so I guess I need such precision.

Comment: Will your input always be an integer? For an integer, you can simply check that only the left most bit is a 1. I added this in my answer

Comment: Very clever, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that `math.log` is giving you [IEEE floating point](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/) with a maximum of 52 bits of precision.

Your answers are correct to within the limits of the representation.